# How to link url and view by a field of serializer in Django

Tags: django, url, serialization, view, hyperlink

I'm Beginner  in Django. I need to link my view and url by a field. but i dont know how to handle that.
The purpose is displayin a list of feedback for every CaseID. here is my code

view:

```
@login_required
def FeedBack(request):
    id=request.GET.get("id", None)
    if id != None:
        result = []
        for res in models.Fact_FeedBack.objects.filter(CaseID__id=id):
            result.append(models.Fact_FeedBack.serializer.__get__(res))
        return render(request, 'CarIA/feedback.html', {'result': result})
```

url:

```
url(r'^casedetail/(?P<case_id>[0-9]+)/feedbacks$', views.FeedBack, name='caria_ShowFeedback'),
```

model:

```
class Fact_FeedBack(models.Model):
    CaseID = models.ForeignKey('Fact_CarCase', related_name='Fact_FeedBack_CaseID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    FeedBackTitle = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    FeedBackDesc = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True)
    FeedBackCommand = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True)
    PublishDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='Fact_FeedBack_UserName', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.CaseID)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def publish(self):
        self.PublishDate = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.FeedBackTitle

    @property
    def serializer(self):
        return {
            'CaseID' : self.CaseID,
            'FeedBackTitle':self.FeedBackTitle,
            'FeedBackDesc':self.FeedBackDesc,
            'FeedBackCommand':self.FeedBackCommand,
            'PublishDate':self.PublishDate,
            'User':self.User,
        }
```

Error I recieve is:

```
FeedBack() got an unexpected keyword argument 'case_id'
```

Thanks for the tips

Comment: You are missing case_id argument in your Feedback function 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views

Comment: change id=request.GET.get("id", None) to id=request.GET.get("case_id", None)